# Avoid rebuilding when trying to preload widgets

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build a system just like tinder where there is a stack of cards a user can swipe and the next few cards are always preloaded.

To do that, I have a `Stack` widget that build a series of cards child widgets and give them the id of the content to load:

```dart
class PostCardStack extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostCardStack({Key key, this.postIds, this.onCardDismissed})
      : super(key: key);

  final List<String> postIds;
  final Function onCardDismissed;

  @override
  _PostCardStackState createState() => _PostCardStackState();
}

class _PostCardStackState extends State<PostCardStack> {
  ValueNotifier<double> _notifier = ValueNotifier<double>(0.0);

  _buildCardStack() {
    List<Widget> cards = [];
    for (String postId in widget.postIds) {
      int idx = widget.postIds.indexOf(postId);
      if (postId == widget.postIds.first) {
        cards.add(CustomDismissible(
            resizeDuration: null,
            dismissThresholds: {CustomDismissDirection.horizontal: 0.2},
            notifier: _notifier,
            key: Key(postId),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              _notifier.value = 0.0;
              widget.onCardDismissed(postId);
            },
            child: SlidablePanel(
              panel: AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: _notifier,
                  child: PostCard(
                    postId: postId,
                  ),
                  builder: (context, _) {
                    return Opacity(
                        opacity: 1 - _notifier.value,
                        child: PostCard(
                          postId: postId,
                        ));
                  }),
            )));
      } else {
        cards.add(AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: _notifier,
            child: PostCard(
              postId: postId,
            ),
            builder: (context, _) {
              return Opacity(
                  opacity: lerpDouble(1 - (0.1 * idx), 1 - ((0.1 * idx) - 0.1),
                      _notifier.value),
                  child: Transform(
                      origin: null,
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                          0.0,
                          lerpDouble(
                              -idx * 35, (-idx * 35 + 35), _notifier.value),
                          0.0)
                        ..scale(
                            lerpDouble(1 - (0.1 * idx), 1 - ((0.1 * idx) - 0.1),
                                _notifier.value),
                            lerpDouble(1 - (0.1 * idx), 1 - ((0.1 * idx) - 0.1),
                                _notifier.value),
                            1),
                      child: PostCard(
                        postId: postId,
                      )));
            }));
      }
    }
    return cards.reversed.toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: _buildCardStack());
  }
}
```

In the `PostCard` widget, I use the `postId` param to fetch the card information and build it when it is ready.

```dart
class PostCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostCard({Key key, this.postId}) : super(key: key);

  final String postId;

  @override
  _PostCardState createState() => _PostCardState();
}

class _PostCardState extends State<PostCard> {
  PostModel post;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("${widget.postId} mounted");
    _fetchPost(widget.postId);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("${widget.postId} disposed");
    super.dispose();
  }

  _fetchPost(String postId) async {
    PostModel fullPost = await blablaFirestore(postId);

    setState(() {
      post = fullPost;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Text(post == null ? "Loading..." : post.text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Everything works fine except when any element of the list of id in the Stack component changes, all the child cards gets rebuilt, therefore loosing their previously loaded state and have to fetch the data again.

If only one element of the list of id change, why are every cards rebuilding? Am I missing something here? :)

Edit: In the question marked as duplicate, the problem is the build method having side effects. I don't believe that this is the case here. In my case, the problem is that state of the PostCards widget is not kept even tho they rebuild with the exact same param (postId)

Cheers!

Comment: could you please show your PostCard code?

Comment: @rémi-rousselet In the question you marked as duplicate, the problem was the build method having side effects. In my case, the problem is that state of the `PostCard`s widget is not kept even tho they rebuild with the exact same param (`postId`)

Comment: That's the same thing. You're doing something wrong inside "build" anyway, otherwise, this problem wouldn't happen (or there's critical information you didn't give us).

Comment: Could you share your PostCard code, especially the way the request is made?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Edited my question with all the code ;)

Comment: Ah, that explains a few things! That's because your `PostCard`s have a different parent depending on some conditions.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Just realized I didn't specify that, but I also get a lot of `FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _PostCardState#65886(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)` in postcard

Comment: @RémiRousselet You mean the `CustomDismissible` and `AnimatedBuilder`? If so, how should I approach solving this problem?

Comment: Either add a `GlobalObjectKey(postId)` on your `PostCard

Answer (score 2):

When `setState` is called the `build` function is called again, and all the `PostCard` widget will be recreated since they are created in the `build` function.

This said, if `PostCard` is a `Stateful` widget the state should not be destroyed (e.g. initState will not be called on them). But you will likely loose the reference to them, which might be why your code is not behaving as you expect (hard to tell from your code).

Maybe you should make the widget where this piece of code is called a `Stateful` widget and create a `List<PostCard> postCards` variable to store your cards, this way you can initialize `postCards` in your `initState` function and they will not be recreated when you call `setState`, thus preserving the reference.

Comment: The code of `Postcard` is really straight forward, It just fetch the card info from the provided `postId` in it's initstate and when it's ready render them in the card instead of a `CircularProgressIndicator`. The weird thing is that they appear to be destroyed (the dispose method is called on every parent rerender)

Comment: Did you try to make the widget a Stateful widget? That should solve your issue.